# Custom IP Range in Azure WAF

Tags: azure, ip, azure-waf

I need to log the traffic coming from a range of IP address in Azure WAF by having custom rules.
For example I need to log the traffic coming from IP range starting from 10.10.

From the Azure documentation, we find how it is done for the last part of the IP but not sure how to do it for the last but one part.
for example : 10.10.10.0/24

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/afds/waf-front-door-configure-ip-restriction

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you will want 10.10.0.0/16.

This is based on the IP range being required to be [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) format (as confirmed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/792475/add-ip-range-azure-front-door-waf-custom-rule)). Not the easiest thing to follow to be honest but the following utility site can be used to confirm; https://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr (screenshot to illustrate)

[image]